# Listen for generic events

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have a function I would like to run on after update of a lot of different text boxes, is it possible to listen for a generic after update event rather than the specific events?

So rather than 100 individual calls to the function, just one listener?

Edit: It would appear we are using a combination of MVVM and traditional code behind.

Here is one of the textboxes:

```
 <TextBox Text="{Binding APhaseFrom}" x:Name="txtFromWhereA" TabIndex="26" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="48" TextWrapping="NoWrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="261" FontSize="26" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Margin="289,656,0,0" GotMouseCapture="txtFromWhereA_GotMouseCapture" GotFocus="txtFromWhereA_GotFocus" Grid.Row="3" />
```

The code from the view Model:

```
public string APhaseFrom
    {
        get { return new string((char[])_f.Rows[1].GetValue("Alpha09")); }
        set
        {
            if (value.Length <= 35)
            {
                _f.Rows[1].SetValue("Alpha09", value);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: String length Longer than 35 Characters.");
            }
        }
    }
```

We also are using some commands for other processes:

```
public ICommand Updatesql
    {
        get;
        internal set;
    }

    private void CreateUpdatesql()
    {
        Updatesql = new RelayCommand(UpdatesqlExecute);
    }

    private void UpdatesqlExecute()
    {
        _f.Update();
    }
```

Should I be using commands or just link the events to functions in the viewmodel?

Comment: Simply attach the listener to all TextBoxes?

Comment: @Ralf As far as I understand that is what he is doing now... He is asking for a way that the event only gets fired once

Comment: @Herrozerro How are the TextBox items being updated? User input?

Comment: Post some code, are you using MVVM (ie View / View Model) ?

Comment: @ChrisLava Yes, user input.  At the moment we have I guess sort of a hybrid of MVVM and traditional event code behind.  I am binding the data using a VeiwModel and we are also using the code behind events for most of our business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using WPF, and if I understand your problem correctly, then the RoutedEvents that WPF uses may help you here. Essentially, events like the `LostFocus` event of a TextBox will bubble up your UI hierarchy and can be handled by a common parent control. Consider this snippet of XAML and codebehind:

```
<StackPanel TextBox.LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus">
    <TextBox></TextBox>
    <TextBox></TextBox>
    <TextBox></TextBox>
</StackPanel>
```

Codebehind:

```
    private void TextBoxLostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Lost Focus!");
    }
```

You will find that the event handler is called for *any* of the three textboxes when focus is lost. The `sender` parameter or `e.Source` can be used to find the textbox that fired the event.

This pattern holds true for any `RoutedEvent`, so things like `Button.Click` or `TextBox.TextChanged` and many more can be caught in this manner.

Comment: I tried this using a grid, the textbox. qualifier is redundant.  It is firing off on every single lost focus, not just text boxes.  Is this because I am using a grid rather than stackpanel?

Comment: No, it's because you've omitted the textbox qualifier. I included it for a reason...

Comment: I used: <Grid TextBox.LostFocus="TextBoxLostFocus"> the textbox part is lighter than the rest and when I hover over it it says "Redundant property type Modifier"

Comment: Also, is there a way to get the original text boxes name from the routed event args.

Comment: I quote my own answer: "The `sender` parameter or `e.Source` can be used to find the textbox that fired the event." If your textbox has a name, you can find it there.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

I removed my previous ideas because I now understand more clearly what you are looking for.

But you definitely need to use the `LostFocus` event.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding APhaseFrom}" x:Name="txtFromWhereA" LostFocus="OnLostFocus" />
```

Comment: That's sorta of what I already have looked at, a single update or save button would work, but that's not what is wanted.  While adding a line of code to all of the hundred or so events, what I am trying to do is have a generic listener just listening for an after update or lost focus.  Hopefully doing it the right way rather that what I have so far.

Comment: @Herrozerro so you want an event to fire after each TextBox has updated? If so, then you need to use the LostFocus event.

Answer (score 1):

Really and truthfully you should be using a single design pattern... ie MVVM when writing WPF applications, each textbox would be bound to a property which implements the INotifyPropertyChange interface.

In the setter of each property you would essentially update the value, fire a property changed event and then either make a call to your method or simply add an event handler on the view model for the PropertyChanged event.

Also... MessageBox.Show is a bad idea in your view models, its hard to unit test it.

Comment: Okay, I think I see.  So the textbox being bound to the property wouldn't change.  I would just change the property to your suggestion.  Do you know of any good tutorials for this?